# Sql adding new column and allowing null to the column with default value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone tell me what's wrong with the below query using SQL Server 2014.
Search a lot but did not find any solution.
Actually am adding a new column and allowing that column to null also with the default value.

Getting error incorrect syntax near for

```
alter table TBL_EMPLOYEE_MASTER add vCityName varchar(50) null Default('') FOR [vCityName]
GO
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: have you check with the documentation for the correct syntax ?

Comment: Just remove the `FOR [vCityName]`... Guess that counts as a typo...

Comment: Just DON'T define an empty string as a default in the first place. That makes no logical sense. In fact, I suggest you define a constraint that will PREVENT an empty string (or equivalent). Either it is NULL or it contains "something" - but not "nothing"

Comment: Additionally, I strongly suggest one explicitly name constraints to facilitate subsequent DDL: `ALTER TABLE TBL_EMPLOYEE_MASTER ADD vCityName varchar(50) NULL CONSTRAINT DF_TBL_EMPLOYEE_MASTER_vCityName DEFAULT('');`

Comment: zero length string as a default value is the devil incarnate.

Comment: Either remove the `FOR [vCityName]` or put a comma between `null` and `Default` so the add column and add constraint become two different clauses (and you should explicitly name the constraint too)

Answer (score 1):

The `for` is unnecessary. Try the query below.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_EMPLOYEE_MASTER] ADD [vCityName] VARCHAR(50) CONSTRAINT DF_TBL_EMPLOYEE_MASTER_vCityName DEFAULT '' NULL
GO
```

This query includes adding a name to the default constraint. Whether it's usefull to allow NULL's **AND** set an empty string as default, is up to you ;)

Small addition, I prefer not to start fieldnames with a "v" (vCityName) because this is also a common naming convention for views.